# Implementing Discord Server Member Join Notification to External Web Server Without Continuous Websocket Connection

Tags: discord, bots, webhooks

I am working on a Discord bot or webhook, and I'm looking for a solution that allows Discord to send a request to my web server every time a user joins a server. Using a websocket for this purpose requires a 24/7 active server, which can be expensive and challenging to maintain.

I've tried searching on Google for a method to achieve this, but unfortunately, I haven't found any relevant results. Can someone **guide me on how to implement a system where Discord automatically sends a request to my specified URL upon a member joining a server**? Any help or pointers to the right resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!